# Chakra UI's Skeleton Component not working under Flexbox properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, chakra-ui, react-loading-skeleton

[image]

I have applied *flex property* to the Box component and inside it, there are two *flex children*, a *circle skeleton*, and a Box containing *two skeletons*.

But it shows only the circle Skeleton component:

[image]

And when I remove *flex properties* from the parent component *Box*, it previews like this :

[image]

After removing *flex property* from the *parent component*, at least it shows all components.

What is the reason behind it, not allowing *flex properties* on the parent Component whose children are the *Skeleton Components*?

There is no precaution written on the official docs inside the Skeleton section related to this behavior.

Anyone who knows?

**Thanking you in advance. :)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No width was set on the Skeletons. You need to set width on the Skeleton/Inner Box or `flex:1` on your inner Box.